# VSTS NuGet Restore dependencies

Tags: azure-devops, nuget-package-restore

I'm trying to put all my old solutions in VSTS, create a build definition and my own NuGet repository.
In my project I referenced external public NuGet packages like iTextSharp.
In VS2017 my solution builds fine,  but in VSTS the following errors occur:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1820,5): Warning MSB3245: Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the assembly "itextsharp, Version=5.5.12.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=8354ae6d2174ddca, processorArchitecture=MSIL". Check to make sure the assembly exists on disk. If this reference is required by your code, you may get compilation errors.
>
> Error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'iTextSharp' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

There is my [build definition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o1tmX.png)

I'm trying to understand why it builds in VS2017 but not in VSTS

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Since you need to restore the packages from your own NuGet repository, you need to specify the package source in configuration file (NuGet.config) and specify that configuration file in NuGet restore task.

Since it is working fine in VS2017, so I think you added the package source in configuration file, then you can add that file to source control and specify in NuGet restore task. (Select **Feeds in my NuGet.config option** in NuGet restore task and specify the file)

Comment: I need to restore package from nurget.org, i think. I don't have nuget.config file, i juste have a package.config which come from nuget maybe. Do i need to create a nuget.config file? In the build log from nuget restore task, a temporary nuget.config file is generated. but didn't care about my dependencies.

Comment: Can you share the detail log on the OneDrive? (Set system.debug variable to true and queue build)

Comment: Do you select Visual Studio 2017 in Visual Studio Build task?

Comment: Yes Visual Studio 2017 is selected. I will not use vsts to build my solution and i will create my nugget package manually. It's working fine. I lost so much time trying to use vsts for that... it's not worth it at all. I will wait for vsts to be as efficient as VS build. vsts didn't support inline declaration in tryParse and some variablesdeclarations. It's too restrictive for the moment. Maybe one days VSTS will be evolved enough. Thx for help even if i didn't succeed to use it properly !

Comment: You can share the detail log on the OneDrive if you have the time.

Comment: Voici un lien vers les logs : www.transfernow.net/840ao2a0gmbn

Comment: Can't find the useful information from log, you can share a sample project if have time.

Comment: I created a new project and copied all methods that don't compile. 
The project has the same build definition (default definition - .Net Desktop). this new project compile in vsts but not the other one